# EF Core 3.1 (LINQ) - how to left join and group by on multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda, ef-core-3.1

Lets say I have 3 relations:
classA(aID#, aName, aNumber), classB(bID#, bName, bNumber, *aId*), classC(cID#, cName, cNumber, *bId*)

and according to that 3 tables with some random data:

classA

| aID | aName | aNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aN1 | 5 |
| 2 | aN2 | 4 |
| 3 | aN3 | 3 |

class B

| aID | aName | aNumber | bID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bN1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | bN2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | bN3 | 5 | 2 |

classC

| aID | aName | aNumber | bID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cN1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | cN2 | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | cN3 | 7 | 3 |

Now, using T-SQL syntax would be like below:

```sql
select a.aID, a.aName, sum(c.cNumber) as SUM
from classA a 
left join classB b on a.aID = b.aId 
left join classC c on b.bID = c.bId
group by a.AID, a.aName, c.Number
```

so I get the result like this:

| aID | aName | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aN1 | 12 |
| 2 | aN2 | 7 |
| 3 | aN3 | 0 |

How to create correct lambda expression syntax according to explanation above?

Comment: When I execute that query (after fixing the typo), I get [6 6 7] in the SUM column (which I expected when summing `c.aNumber`). See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/850137/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```cs
var query =
    from a in ctx.A
    from b in ctx.B.Where(b => a.aID == b.aId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from c in ctx.C.Where(c => b.bID == c.bId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    group c by new { a.aID, a.aName, c.cNumber } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.aID,
        g.Key.aName,
        Sum = g.Sum(x => x.cNumber)
    };
```

And using LINQ Method chain syntax:

```cs
var query2 = ctx.A
    .SelectMany(a => ctx.B.Where(b => a.aID   == b.aId).DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, b) => new {a, b})
    .SelectMany(t => ctx.C.Where(c => t.b.bID == c.bId).DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, c) => new {t, c})
    .GroupBy(t => new {t.t.a.aID, t.t.a.aName, t.c.cNumber}, t => t.c)
    .Select(g => new {g.Key.aID, g.Key.aName, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.cNumber)});
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you transform this syntax into a LINQ method syntax?

Comment: I can but will be a mess. Better to keep query syntax when you have a lot of joins. Anyway ReSharper can do that in on click.